# Controlling the width of R console

Tags: r

In the documentation of `options` function it says, `width` argument

> controls the maximum number of columns on a line used in printing
>   vectors, matrices and arrays, and when filling by cat.
>
> Columns are normally the same as characters except in East Asian
>   languages.

What it refers to as columns? It is the number of characters?

If `options(width=50)` what this `50` means?

Comment: Yes. Columns are the horizontal position on the screen, measured in characters; line numbers are the vertical. Some editors/error messages/etc. display both.

Comment: If `options(width=50)` does it mean I can print 0:9, 5 times? But it doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: It means there are 50 columns width of space available to print methods. Some of that will usually be occupied by indices, spaces, etc., though. In practice some wrapping happens before it actually hits the limit so as to fit the whole next element. Also, if you print an element wider than the limit, e.g. `paste(rep(0, 500), collapse = '')`, it (RStudio, at least) will use all available space before wrapping, ignoring `width` entirely.

Comment: `cat` is useful to see width as it does not print indices, quotes, etc., but it also doesn't respect the `width` option (you don't really want it to in its file-writing purpose), but it does have a `fill` parameter that works similarly. Try `cat(rep(0:9, 5), fill = 50)`, and you'll see that it takes 2 lines because it includes 50 numbers and 50 spaces.